# How can one be sure to not create a new account on logging in to 1 of the StackExchange family of sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I have accidentally created more than five duplicate accounts spread across several of the Stack Exchange family of sites. I did not intend to do it, I did not want to do it, and I did not know that I had done it until later I come back and wanted to accept someone's answer to a question of mine, and there was no acceptance check mark there that I can see, and most of my rep is missing.

I know I must be seriously dense about this, and it is certainly true that I can not remember from one session to another which browser I was using or which social media site I used to log in. I would prefer not to log in with a social media site at all, but sometimes it seems like there is no option, or at least, no obvious option.

3ventic explained, here: [Can I have a common account across the Stack Exchange family of sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214087/can-i-have-a-common-account-across-the-stack-exchange-family-of-sites) that I can associate my accounts and use a common login. Thanks, 3ventic! But this will not help if I keep creating new accounts by accident.

Could somebody explain to me in words of one syllable (well, lets say one or two) just what I need to do, or not to do, to always log into an existing accounts rather than creating new ones, across browsers and such? I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Same OpenID account == same account across the SE family of sites. If you have more than one OpenID account, then associate those all with one of your accounts on the network.

Comment: To associate additional OpenID accounts, click on *my logins* on your profile page, and use *add more logins...* in that dialog box.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the same login method, and you'll get into the same account. That's guaranteed to work. If you can't recall which method you used, consider settling on one to consistently use from now on (Stack Exchange's own login is one to consider: it's always the first option, and it's secure).

There are also ways of getting into the same account *without* using the same login method.

1. You can associate more than one login method with one account, so that if you use either you're logged into the same account. (Click *my logins* on your profile page, then *add more logins*).
2. You can create separate accounts, and then later merge them, which ultimately has the same effect. (Use the *Contact Us* link at the bottom of any page to merge profiles.)
3. I believe that if you use Facebook or Google to log in, you'll get the same account either way, because Stack Exchange trusts both of them to validate e-mail addresses, so if both say you have the same e-mail address, you'll get into the same SE account. I'm not quite sure about this, but I think I recall reading it somewhere. (I've never used Facebook to log into anything, on principle, because I hate them.)